# Problem with user data of ec2 cloudformation instance

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops, amazon-ecs

I have a problem when i put sh code in the cloudformation template, this json values is on the launchconfig

```
"UserData": {
  "Fn::Base64": {
    "Fn::Join": [
      "", [
        "#!/bin/bash \necho ECS_CLUSTER=erp-dev >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

my cloudformation template launch an ec2 instance, after the instance launch is finished i check the configuration here  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhFdC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyxUa.png)

the new line character is printed literally and i dont know what is going on, if i check the logs, this is for /var/log/cloud-init-output.log
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlFUY.png)

this configuration is for ecs, before it worked very well but due to this problem I have to figure out how to make the relationship between the cluster and the instance in another way.

Anybody can help me with that new line characther in the file?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA29S.png)

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.  Each line could be added as a list item to the `"Fn::Join"` list.

```
{
  "UserData": {
    "Fn::Base64": {
      "Fn::Join": [
        "", [
          "#!/bin/bash\n",
          "echo ECS_CLUSTER=erp-dev >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you explain whats not working. did you check the ecs.config file

Answer (score 1):

https://serverfault.com/questions/981763/how-do-i-set-user-data-when-using-the-aws-cli-cli-input-json-argument

A comment here says that they had trouble using one line for user data when they used base64.  If you can do it without that, it may work.